# make grid items automatically fill empty spaces

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, css-grid

I have the following CSS grid system that has 4 kinds of different cell sizes:
small, wide, tall and large.
In a desktop version I've made them in a puzzle like shape that looks good but to make it mobile friendly I need the cells with a class small to automatically fill up the blank spaces that appear.

Here's the css:

```
.portfolio-holder {
    margin: 66px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.portfolio {
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(13, 200px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 24px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.portfolio_hat {
    background: #fd3a1e;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 14px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top left;
    position: relative;
}

.portfolio_hat.tall {
    grid-row: span 2;
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.portfolio_hat.wide {
    grid-row: span 1;
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.portfolio_hat.small {
    grid-row: span 1;
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.portfolio_hat.tall {
    grid-row: span 2;
    grid-column: span 2;
}

@media (max-width:860px) {
    .portfolio {
        grid-template-rows: repeat(26, 40vw);
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 40vw);
    }
}
```

and the HTML looks something like this:

```
<section class="portfolio-holder">
    <div id="port" class="portfolio">
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <!-- divs like the four above are generated from MYSQL DATABASE and there's a lot of them in a chaotic order -->
    </div>
</section>
```

I want a way to make sure that no matter the number of columns in the grid I won't get any empty spaces.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

> The grid-auto-flow CSS property controls how the auto-placement algorithm works, specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.

```css
.portfolio-holder {
    margin: 66px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.portfolio {
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(13, 200px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 24px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
grid-auto-flow: row dense;/*  here your CSS update */
}
.portfolio_hat {
  background: #fd3a1e;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio_hat.tall {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.portfolio_hat.wide {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.portfolio_hat.small {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.portfolio_hat.tall {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

@media (max-width:860px) {
.portfolio {
    grid-template-rows: repeat(26, 40vw);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 40vw);
   }
}
div {/* see them for demo */
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio-holder">
    <div id="port" class="portfolio">
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat tall"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat small"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat wide"></div>
        <div href="#" class="portfolio_hat large"></div>
        <!-- divs like the four above are generated from MYSQL DATABASE and there's a lot of them in a chaotic order -->
    </div>
</section>
```